# Coarsened Exact Matching with cem package- Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact)

Tags: r, error-handling, matching

I'm trying to perform coarsened exact matching on the following data.

```
> dput(head(cem_data))
structure(list(sex = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), age = c(40, 59, 53, 
60, 49, 60), edlev = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3), sw = c(44, 17, 10, 
41, 26, 23), sw2 = c(15, 1, 5, 34, 5, 6), som = c(2.14, 0.14, 
1.86, 3, 1.71, 2.14), som_2 = c(0.71, 0.14, 2, 2.57, 1.71, 2.14
), ap = c(3.5, 1.5, 1.33, 3.33, 2.67, 2.17), ap_2 = c(3, 0.17, 
2.33, 3, 0.83, 1.67), dep = c(2.83, 0.17, 0.33, 2.83, 2.17, 2.33
), dep_2 = c(1.17, 0, 0.33, 2.33, 0.83, 1), int = c(2.86, 1.43, 
1, 2, 2.29, 2.14), int_2 = c(2.29, 0.57, 0.14, 2.57, 1.71, 1.43
), pho = c(3.2, 0, 0, 3.4, 0.8, 0.4), pho_2 = c(1.6, 0, 0, 3.2, 
0, 0.4), psy_b = c(2.67, 0.11, 0.83, 3.06, 1.61, 1.72), psy_b_2 = c(1.11, 
0.06, 0.89, 2.67, 0.94, 1.28), s_wirk = c(4, 2.2, 1.6, 3.2, 1.4, 
2.2), s_wirk_2 = c(2.8, 0.8, 1.8, 2.6, 1.6, 1.4), soz_b = c(2.75, 
1.5, 1, 2.25, 1.25, 1.5), soz_b_2 = c(2.75, 1, 1, 2.25, 1.5, 
1.25), soz_u = c(0.75, 0.75, 1.75, 3.25, 1, 3.25), soz_u_2 = c(1, 
0.25, 1.75, 2.5, 2.5, 2), wohl = c(3.6, 1.4, 1.8, 3.4, 3, 3), 
    wohl_2 = c(2, 0.6, 1.4, 2.8, 2.2, 1.2), au_bei_aufn = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), age_reha = c(40.9890410958904, 59.3945205479452, 
    53.372602739726, 60.2, 49.3342465753425, 60.7534246575342
    ), group_format = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(6L, 
7L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 29L), class = "data.frame")
```

With the following code:

```
require(cem)
voll_data <- voll_data %>% 
  select(-c("auf_nr", "icd_10_1", "icd_10_2", "icd_10_3", "icd_10_4","icd_10_5", "bdi_date", "aufnahme", "entlassung")) %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor,as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric)


cem_data <- data.frame(na.omit(voll_data))
#cem_data_s <- scale(cem_data[,5:26])
#cem_data <- cbind.data.frame(cem_data[, 1:4], cem_data_s, cem_data[, 27:36])
variables <- c("age", "sex", "edlev", "sw","au_bei_aufn")

ungleich2 <- imbalance(cem_data$group_format, data=cem_data)
```

However, following error is being shown, when calculating the "matt".

Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : attempt to select less than one element in get1index

7.
(function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x, i, exact = exact))(x, ..., exact = exact)

6.
`[[.data.frame`(data, treatment)

5.
data[[treatment]]

4.
is.factor(x)

3.
as.factor(data[[treatment]])

2.
cem.main(treatment = treatment, data = data, cutpoints = cutpoints, drop = drop, k2k = k2k, method = method, mpower = mpower, verbose = verbose, baseline.group = baseline.group, keep.all = keep.all)

1.
cem(treatment = cem_data$group_format, data = cem_data, drop = "sw2", cutpoints = list(age = agecut), grouping = list(edlev_gr))

```
# automated coarsening

matt <- cem(cem_data$group_format, data = cem_data, drop= "sw2")
print(matt)
```

Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!!